# Is there any way to programmatically tell a USB modem to reset?

Tags: usb, hardware, modem, power-management

I have a USB modem on a server which occasionally needs to be turned off/on again to receive SIM updates and I can't reboot the server as we rely on it to serve various web pages.

Is there any way to do this programmatically? An AT command? Power down the USB port?

I don't always have access to the server so unplugging it and plugging it back in isn't an option unfortunately.

We're coding in C++/CLI if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if someone knew of a generic solution to this, but for the Option Globetrotter 452 I'm using, the manufacturer reports that issuing an `AT_ORESET` command will instruct the device to reboot ...just in case anyone else wants to do this.